# I am extremely stuck on this computing homework, can anyone help me?

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.5

My teacher set me this homework and I have no idea what is going on. I have completed the first question; however, I cannot find a solution to the rest.
**Can anyone Help?**
The Questions are:
1. Amend line 12 and 13 so that the program works.
2. Using the variable content and a loop, print every item out individually
3. If the program finds the word 'All', it outputs "I found the mystery word"

Extension: Count the number of 'i's in the text file and outputs the total
here is the code:

```
writeFile = open("test.txt",'w')
writeFile.write("World! \n")
writeFile.write("All \n")
writeFile.write("Of \n")
writeFile.write("This \n")
writeFile.write("Is \n")
writeFile.write("On \n")
writeFile.write("Seperate \n")
writeFile.write("Lines! \n")
writeFile.close()
#Leave all the above code alone
readFile = open("test.txt", 'r')
content = readFile.read().split(" ")
readFile.close()
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to ask your teacher for help, or review the notes you've presumably taken in class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you started!

https://repl.it/GtmZ/0

After your "content = readfile" line, you need a for loop then some if then else constructs. You also need an if statement to check for the "All".

```
for val in content:
  if val.strip(' \t\n\r') == "All": 
    print("I found the mystery word")
  else: 
    print(val)
```

Make sure you learn what these things do! Google will help with this

Comment: Thank you very much. This helped a lot.